# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x \arctan x)-e^{x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1+2x^4}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I've tried to solve this limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x \arctan x)-e^{x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1+2x^4}-1}$$

Here,
$$\frac{\ln (1+x \arctan x)-e^{x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1+2x^4}-1}$$ $$\sim \frac{(x \arctan x-x^2)(\sqrt{1+2x^4}+1)}{2x^4}$$ $$\sim \frac{(x \arctan x-x^2)}{x^4}= \frac{ \arctan x-x}{x^3} \sim \frac{x-x}{x^3} \sim 0$$

But the final result should be $-\frac{4}{3}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look, in every question what you are doing is actually correct but not uptil the approximation. For this kind of questions you need to choose the approximation as much as you can to eliminate.For example seeing $x^2$ as max degree in the problem you need to approximate such a way that functions in the value approximate by polynomials more than that max degree .If you do so all your limits will give your desired solution

Comment: It is better to stick to limit theorems and use $=$ instead of $\sim$ (because most beginners are not aware of the nuances of how $\sim$ works).

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is from the first step.Emm...in fact,$$\lim \frac{{\ln (1 + x\arctan x)}}{{\sqrt {1 + 2{x^4}}  - 1}} = \frac{{\ln (1 + x\arctan x)(\sqrt {1 + 2{x^4}}  + 1)}}{{2{x^4}}} = \infty , \\ \lim \frac{{{e^{{x^2}}} - 1}}{{\sqrt {1 + 2{x^4}}  - 1}} = \frac{{({e^{{x^2}}} - 1)(\sqrt {1 + 2{x^4}}  + 1)}}{{2{x^4}}} =  \infty $$
However,when $${f_1} \sim \alpha ,{f_2} \sim \beta $$ but $$\frac{\alpha }{g} = \infty or\frac{\beta }{g} = \infty $$
you can't apply
$$\frac{{{f_1} - {f_2}}}{g} \sim \frac{{\alpha  - \beta }}{g}$$

I don't know if I made it clear to you...

Comment: I'm afraid not    , i didn't understand where is the mistake

Comment: For example,${x^2} + x = x(x + 1) \sim x (x \to 0)$,but $$\frac{{({x^2} + x) - x}}{{{x^2}}} \sim \frac{{x - x}}{{{x^2}}}$$ is wrong.Note that "equivalent infinitesimal" can be only used if the formula has only multiplication and division.When there is a minus in the middle, you should divide it into two formulas, and then apply the rule to the numerator and the denominator respectively. @ Anne

Comment: In fact,$$\lim \frac{{\ln (1 + x\arctan x) - ({e^{{x^2}}} - 1)}}{{x\arctan x - {x^2}}} = 4$$

Comment: so how should i do in the problem?

Comment: Maybe you need to use Taylor series.  As @ Math_Buddy said,  you need to choose the approximation as much as you can to eliminate. It's not difficult.I have been thinking about the other ways.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x \arctan x)-e^{x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1+2x^4}-1}$$
You need to use Taylor series:
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x (x-\dfrac {x^3}3+...)-(1+x^2+\dfrac {x^4}{2}+o(x^4))+1}{x^4}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ (x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3-\dfrac {x^4}2+o(x^4))-x^2-\dfrac {x^4}{2}+o(x^4)}{x^4}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ -\dfrac {x^4}3-\dfrac {x^4}2-\dfrac {x^4}{2}+o(x^4)}{x^4}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ -\dfrac {x^4}3- {x^4}+o(x^4)}{x^4}$$
$$L= -\dfrac {1}3-1=-\dfrac  43$$
Where :
$$\sqrt{1+2x^4}=1+x^4+o(x^4)$$
$$e^{x^2}=1+x^2+\dfrac {x^4}2+o(x^4)$$
$$\ln (1+x)=x-\dfrac {x^2}2 +...$$
$$\arctan x = x-\dfrac {x^3}3+o(x^4)$$

---

for the arctan and log term
$$S=\ln (1+x (x-\dfrac {x^3}3+...)$$
Remember that we have the Taylor serie for log:
$$\ln (1+z)=z-\dfrac {z^2}2$$
So that we have:
$$S=\ln (1+x (x-\dfrac {x^3}3+...)$$
$$S=\ln (1 +(x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3+...)$$
$$S=(x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3+...)-\dfrac 12(x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3+...)^2$$
We only keep terms with exponent less or equal to four...
$$S=(x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3+...)-\dfrac 12(x^4 \ \color {red}{ \text { + more terms with exponent> 4}})$$
We don't need the terms that have exponent greater than four. Because we take the limit at zero and all these terms will be zeros. They play no role. So that:
$$S=x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3-\dfrac {x^4}2+o(x^4)$$

Comment: I dont' understant what happens in the last passage, a $$-\frac{x^4}{2}$$ appears in the numerator

Comment: It gives $-x^4$ since you have that term twice @Anne

Comment: Collect all the terms with exponent $x^4$ what do you get ? @Anne

Comment: yes I got it but why there is such a term, it should be a $\frac{x^5}{5}$ because it derives from the serie of $arctg x$

Comment: I added some lines at the end @Anne

Comment: Since the denominator is in $x^4$ all the terms at the numerator that are greater than 4 will vanish since $x^5/x^4=x$ and the limit of x is zero...@Anne is this clear ? We dont need to bother with term like $x^5$ or greater.

Comment: yes, I know but the term in question is $$- \frac{x^2}{4}$$  why it is of the forth grade and not fifth? Where does it come from?

Comment: You square $S=(x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3+...)-\dfrac 12(x^2-\dfrac {x^4}3+...)\color {red}{^2}$  @Anne $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$

Answer (score 0):

The handling of denominator is easy. Multiplying the expression under limit with $$\frac{\sqrt{1+2x^4}+1}{\sqrt{1+2x^4}+1}$$ we can see that the limit in question is equal to the limit of the expression $$\frac{\log(1+x\arctan x) - e^{x^2}+1}{x^4}$$ Split this expression into three parts as $$\frac{\log(1+x\arctan x) - x\arctan x} {(x\arctan x) ^2}\cdot\frac{(\arctan x) ^2}{x^2}+\frac{\arctan x - x}{x^3}-\frac{e^{x^2}-1-x^2}{x^4}$$ For the first term substitute $u=x\arctan x$ and conclude that it tends to $-1/2$. You can also find the limit of second term easily as $-1/3$. For third term just put $t=x^2$ and observe that it tends to $1/2$. The desired answer is thus $$-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{4}{3}$$

---

The issue with your approach is the wrong use of equivalents ($\sim$ notation). Unless you are familiar with the rules of this notation avoid using it and instead stick to the usual limit laws/theorems/rules.